# Is 'Archfragen' a synonym for 'Archiv' or not a real word?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Curiously, Google [translates "Archfragen"](https://translate.google.com/#de/en/Archfragen) as "Archives", which I suspect is incorrect.  "Archiv" appears to be the norm.  Also, "archfragen" is largely absent from Google Books.

Has anyone ever seen or heard "*Archfragen*" in use?  Is it a compound word built from the noun "*Fragen*" (questions)?  If so, is the first syllable derived from the Greek root *[arkhos](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=arkhos)*?

Comment: More context, please! Where did you find this word? In which sentence was ist used? Please quote the hole paragraph where you found this word. We are not able to give a well-founded answer if we don't know the context! Btw: Forget the concept of »real words«! People invent new words every day. If you can use it in a meaningful way, it is real. There is nothing like a »complete list of real words«.

Comment: Google "translates" quite a lot of nonsense. [Archklagen](https://translate.google.com/#de/en/Archklagen) turns into "archaeological finds" - but this is entirely made up by some algorithm. The **only** Google hit for ["Archfragen"](https://books.google.de/books?id=nCxgAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA168&ots=omCSgqejCh&dq=%22Archfragen%22&hl=de&pg=PA168#v=onepage&q=%22Archfragen%22&f=false) is a scanning error from *Hirschfänger*.

Comment: Algorithms shouldn't supersede accepted translations of actual language usage.  (Or as @Jan suggested, should at least throw an error instead of attempting to translate words with no precedent whatsoever.)  It's misleading and casts doubt upon Google Translate as a research tool.  Do you have a preferred online translator?

Comment: As soon as you add more words, Archfragen is no longer translated to archives but to arch queries: https://translate.google.com/#de/en/Archfragen%20ist%20ein%20unbekanntes%20Wort

Comment: Good point @Iris, and clever sentence to translate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not consider *Archfragen* a real word. It looks like the plural of a compound ending in *Frage* but the proposed first stem *Arch* does not exist. Apart from the first four letters, there is no immediate connection to *Archiv;* it might as well be *Arche* (similar to identical pronunciation of those first four letters *Arch).*

Why Google Translate decides to translate *Archfragen* as *archives* rather than throwing an error is their secret.

I would love to know where you found it, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and for confirming that the theoreized stem *Arch* does not exist in German.  I formed *Archfragen* myself and then sought a translation.  First, I thought of the poet Rilke's famous injunction to "*Leben Sie jetzt die Fragen*" – "Live the questions now."  He advised that we embrace questioning as a mode of living, and learn to "love the questions themselves".  *Fragen* also acknowledges the many German thinkers who vocally questioned their society – Luther, Nietzsche, Heidegger, and others. I was thinking of an "*arch-question*" – asking the chief and highest question.

Comment: This was triggered by a question in the English Language group, asking to name *“the act of asking a dangerous question”* -- see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/363193/a-word-to-describe-the-act-of-asking-a-dangerous-question-in-a-search-for-the -- to that, I formulated the answer *heresiarchy*, then added another iterration to my answer with *heresiarch-fragen*.  (Some wordplay at work here.)

Comment: English *Arch-* is *Erz-* in German, and *Erz* (ore) is related to *ehern* (iron adj.). So what you are looking for is a **eherne Frage**. This is a valid term with no defined meaning yet. Though, **ehernes Gesetz** exists.

Comment: @Janka *Erz-* (prefix) and *Erz* (ore) are not related. So your interpretation has an etymological gap (you could've gone for EN *arch* = DE *Bogen, Gewölbe*, too). *Erzfrage* interpreted with the prefix would just mean a *quintessential question* or an *important question*.

Comment: @Janka’s 1st point is correct, tho. _Ur-_ is also related and _Urfrage_ would be less confusing than _Erzfrage_ – for similar reasons, I guess, ‘archenemy’ is sometimes _Erbfeind_, not _Erzfeind_. _Arch**e**frage_ may work in sophisticatd speech. However, these would be understood as synonyms to _Grundfrage_, _Ausgangsfrage_, _grundlegende_, _eigentliche_, _wirkliche_, _wahre_ or _[alles] entscheidende Frage_ at best (also see _Gretchenfrage_, _Kasus Knacktus_). They fit Einstein’s “proper question” from en#363193, but don’t really imply danger – _ketzerische Frage_ would, but fails otherwise.